# Model training on GPU slows down when closing the monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, gpu

I'm currently training a model on my M1 Max (Sonoma OS). When I have the laptop open, it takes around 1 sec/iteration. As the training takes many hours, I have the laptop closed or locked from time to time. When I unlock the screen again, it takes around 40 sec/iteration. What causes this drop in performance?

(Maybe it only works hard when I'm looking?)

Comment: Possibly a load of other tasks need to run when you open your laptop. Does the performance improve after a while?